# System.Net.Http version not lining up in the references list

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

We have a project on .Net 4.6.1 that we've added IdentityServer packages to.

One error we're getting is apparently solved by updating the System.Net.Http.dll to version 4.3.3 (https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1116)

Problem seems to be that VS 2017 (15.7.3) only references `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.Http.dll` and not `packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.3\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll` even if I manually add it. At least that's the path shown in the reference details window and the version that ends up in the bin folder.

Looking in the .csproj it shows

`<Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.3\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>`

One other things that complicates this is that there's no matrix between NuGet versions, file versions, and assembly versions that I could find to help me figure this out.

I'm checking multiple environments but I can only get the file version and there's nothing to cross check that against.

NuGet Package 4.3.3 = `File Version:   4.6.25705.1`

The version in the framework dir = `4.6.26011.1`

Some version in one of our envs that doesn't work = `4.6.25514.4`